# Very basic C++ error

Tags: c++, fstream

Hey guys, I'm writing the simplest thing ever, just creating an ifstream to read in a text file and I have a weird error. Here is the code (note : the '<' missing for iostream and fstream are well written in my code but I couldn't write them here)

```
#include "genlib.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include "random.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "map.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
 ifstream in;
 in.open("Hamlet.txt");
 if (in.fail()) Error("Could not open file");
 return 0;
}
```

I get the following error after the ifstream in; line : "error : expected unqualified-id before '=' token"

Any idea what's going wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Your code compiles fine without Error. Error maybe the reason for all your trouble.

Comment: What's with all the extraneous includes?

Comment: Are you sure you want to include `"map.h"` (not `<map>`), `"vector.h"` (not `<vector>`)?

Answer (score 4):

The only thing unusual past `ifstream in;` is the `Error` call.  My wild guess is that it's a poorly written macro.  Try this instead:

```
int main() {
 ifstream in;
 in.open("Hamlet.txt");
 if (in.fail()) { Error("Could not open file"); }
 return 0;
}
```

Note the new braces around `Error`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
using namespace std;
```

to use arbitrary  names from the library without qualification. Otherwise, the declaration must be

```
std::ifstream in;
```

There is also the option

```
using std::ifstream;
```

but I wouldn't recommend it, since you probably won't be writing out `std::ifstream` all that often.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that in one of your own include files ("genlib.h" and "simpio.h" seem non-Standard), that you're #defined "in"

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file directly in the constructor:

```
ifstream inf ( "Hamlet.txt" , ifstream::in );
```

Answer (score 0):

use std::ifstream

(and provide compilable code; those are not all standard headers, and what is Error()?)